# Self-assignment through ternary operator

Tags: javascript, php, ternary-operator

Is it possible for a variable to be assigned a value through a ternary operator, without having to refer to the same variable twice?

For example, is there a way that something like this:

```
a=a=="1"?"yes":"no";
```

can be done like this?:

```
a=="1"?"yes":"no";
```

I know the line above probably doesn't work, so I'm asking for a short alternative, given the first line.

This isn't much of an issue with small variable names (like the example above). However, it would be nice if there was a way when using arrays and larger variable names, to help keep code compact. I would be interested in both Javascript and PHP solutions.

Comment: No there is no way (for php)

Comment: No, your second way won't work.  You will need to do something like your first way.

Comment: You have to necessarily access the variable for reading and then for writing.

Comment: I recently tried the following in PHP: $a="1"?"yes":"no"; which always returns "yes", so at least in PHP there is some form of assignment happening, albeit not always correct.

Comment: @TristanBailey That will always assign `"yes"` to `$a` regardless of its prior value.

Comment: Ternary Operator is simply replacement for if(){   //assignment  }else{  //assignment   }. Using ternary operator you are just checking the Equality or Inequality of statement. There is no assignment till, for assigning value on the basis of ternary operator execution you have to write an assignment statement As you are doing in your example.

Comment: @TristanBailey Are you sure this is working as you are thinking??? or it working like $a="1" ? "yes" : "no"; this will be executed like (assignment) ? "yes": "no"; and your assignment always gets executed and $a="1" will be treated as "1" and you statement will be 1 ? "yes" : "no";. Now put it into IF...ELSE like if(1){"yes"}else{"no"} and if(1) will always get TRUE.

Comment: It seems that with the PHP example I provided, it is first assigning "1" to the variable $a, then checking to see if it is True, which it will _always_ be, thus always returning "yes". Of course, I could use If and Else clauses, but was looking for a brief, single line alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the ternary operator is strictly defined as:

```
p ? vt : vf
```

With `p` an expression that results in a boolean (thus a test), `vt` the value in case `p` is true and `vf` in case the test is false. There are no means to introduce a *side-effect*. The test of course (that can be a function call or anything), can result in side effects.

There is - as far as I know - in no case an operator that has such side effects. This would probably also be a bad idea: side effects should be well documented and be a bit explicit. If things happen without any syntactical warning, source code becomes hard to read, debug and understand.

You can indeed assign the result to a variable like:

In *JavaScript*:

```
var x = 3;
var x = (x < 3) ? "smaller" : "larger";
```

Or in *PHP*:

```
$x = 3;
$x = ($x < 3) ? "smaller" : "larger";
```

Here you however warn with the `=` operator that the value of `x` will change after that instruction.

Answer (score -1):

Check this

```
<?php
$a = 5;    
$a = ($a==5) ? 'yes' : 'no';    
echo 'the result is '.$a; // the result is yes
?>
```

Comment: Except... you have just put brackets around a second occurrence of the same variable, effectively _extending_ upon the first line of code in my question. I want to both check the variable and assign a value to it, without typing the same variable more than once.

Comment: Hi @Tristan Bailey, The line no.2 check the variable $a and based on the condition the new value of the $a is assigned. Without the line no.1 the result of echo will be "the result is no".

Comment: Hi @Tristan Bailey, I have given a explanation for my answer. The variable need to be assigned a value before it is checked this was I have tried to express from my answer.